# String does not contain a date

Tags: string, pandas, date, dataframe

I have a DataFrame With This Column :

```
Mi_Meteo['Time_Instant'].head():

0    2013/11/14 17:00
1    2013/11/14 18:00
2    2013/11/14 19:00
3    2013/11/14 20:00
4    2013/11/14 21:00
Name: Time_Instant, dtype: object
```

After Doing Some Inspection This is What I realised :

```
Mi_Meteo['Time_Instant'].value_counts():

2013/12/09 02:00    33
2013/12/01 22:00    33
2013/12/11 10:00    33
2013/12/05 09:00    33
.
.
.
.
2013/11/16 02:00    21
2013/11/07 10:00    11
2013/11/17 22:00    11
DateTIme            3
```

So I striped it:

```
Mi_Meteo['Time_Instant'] = Mi_Meteo['Time_Instant'].str.rstrip('DateTIme')# Cause Otherwise I would get this Error When Converting : 'Unknown string format'
```

And Then I tried To Convert it :

```
Mi_Meteo['Time_Instant'] = pd.to_datetime(Mi_Meteo['Time_Instant'])
```

But I Get This Error:

```
String does not contain a date.
```

Any Suggestion Would Be Much Appreciated , Thank U all.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late, why don't you use this:

```
Mi_Meteo['Time_Instant'] = pd.to_datetime(Mi_Meteo['Time_Instant'], errors='coerce')
```

In the [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) document a description of the 'errors' parameter:

> errors{‘ignore’, ‘raise’, ‘coerce’}, default ‘raise’ If ‘raise’, then
>   invalid parsing will raise an exception.
>
> If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaT.
>
> If ‘ignore’, then invalid parsing will return the input.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error - it turns out that two of my dates were empty:  ' '.

To find the row index of the problematic dates I used the following list comprehension:

```
badRows =   [n for n,x in enumerate(df['DATE'].tolist()) if x.strip() in ['']]
```

This returned a list, containing the indices of the rows in the 'DATE' column that were causing the problems:

```
[745672, 745673]
```

Can then delete these rows in place:

```
df.drop(df.index[badRows],inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble reproducing your error, so I cannot be sure if this will fix the issue you have. If not then please try to provide a minimum sample of code/data that reproduces your error.

This is what I tried to reproduce your situation:

```
lzt = ['2013/11/16 02:00 ',
       '2013/11/07 10:00 ',
       '2013/11/17 22:00 ',
       'DateTIme',
       'DateTIme',
       'DateTIme']
ser = pd.Series(lzt)
ser = ser.str.rstrip('DateTIme')
ser = pd.to_datetime(ser)
```

But as I said I got no error, so either we have a different version of pandas or there's something else wrong with your data. Using rstrip leave some blank string data:

```
0    2013/11/16 02:00 
1    2013/11/07 10:00 
2    2013/11/17 22:00 
3                     
4                     
5
```

which for me gives NaT (not a time) when I run pd.to_datetime on it:

```
Out[34]: 
0   2013-11-16 02:00:00
1   2013-11-07 10:00:00
2   2013-11-17 22:00:00
3                   NaT
4                   NaT
5                   NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I'd say it's better practice to remove the unwanted rows all together:

```
ser = ser[ser != 'DateTIme']

Out[39]: 
0   2013-11-16 02:00:00
1   2013-11-07 10:00:00
2   2013-11-17 22:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

See if that works, otherwise please give enough information to reproduce the error.

Comment: Thank's for the help , but i think you are right , there's something wrong , cause when i try to run  the code you provided me i still get this error : String does not contain a date !!

Comment: This is Because it dose not strip the 'DateTIme' avec after running the code  ser = ser.str.rstrip('DateTIme') , which is weird !!

Comment: Don't use rstrip, instead use ser = ser[ser != 'DateTIme'] to filter out the unwanted rows.

What version of python are you running and what version of pandas do you have? Type: pd.__version__ for pandas

Comment: so , the pandas version that i have is the 0.22.0 & i tried the ser = ser[ser != 'DateTIme'] line and after checking  'DateTIme' was there again !!!

Comment: even after updating pandas  to the 0.24.2 version and running the ser = ser[ser != 'DateTIme'] line , DateTIme was there !!

Comment: Just using my code above? Not using your dataframe right? Go to https://jupyter.org/try and try it out there to prove to yourself it works, then you know it's your python distro.

Comment: no no , i tried the syntax , but i used my dataframe.

Comment: Try with the code above where I create the dataframe too. Then you can see if the issue is with your data specifically, and not with your distro

Comment: when i run your code , & especially when i run the last line :    ser = ser[ser != 'DateTIme']    , i get this error :  could not convert string to Timestamp !!!!

Comment: As I said don't use your dataframe. Use the dataframe created above. I don't get an error with that. Then you can troubleshoot if it's your data or your distro. If you then want you can give a complete minimum code segment so someone else can reproduce your error. If you can do that someone can more easily help you, and in trying it you may solve yourself.

Comment: Here, I put the code on colab. Run it there: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1y4MpxSoshh-zQA_Tvm1-NStArYrzNVAM

I'm not getting an error. You shouldn't either. If it's exactly the same code you're running on your machine, then there may be something wrong with your pandas or python (version?) and ya might just try a resinstall.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions to this:

Either you can make the error disappear by using `coerce` in `errors` argument of `pd.to_datetime()` as follows:`Mi_Meteo['Time_Instant'] = pd.to_datetime(Mi_Meteo['Time_Instant'], errors='coerce')`

Or if you are interested to know which dates have the unparsable values, you can search for them by converting each value at a time as follows. Ths will work regardless of the type or format of the wrong value:

```
dates = []
wrong_dates = []
for i in Mi_Meteo['Time_Instant'],unique():
    try: 
        date = pd.to_datetime(i)
        dates.append(i)
    except:
        wrong_dates.append(i)
```

In the `wrong_dates` list you will have all the wrong values while in `dates`, all the right values